# Do American cops shoot black people more than white people in similar cases?

Tags: united-states, police, racism

I want to know if the US police is really prejudiced against black people.

I would most like statistics that answer the question: Do American cops shoot black people more than white people in similar cases?

Other helpful statistics are welcome. 
In example: How many police shooting cases against black people and against white people? How many police shooting cases against black people and against white people from similar socioeconomic background?

Comment: Does this question from Skeptics Stack Exchange help you? [Are African Americans victims of a disproportionate number of police killings?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34539/are-african-americans-victims-of-a-disproportionate-number-of-police-killings)

Comment: thanks @Philipp, it is a good answer. I still would be happy for more statistics.

Comment: Also "shoot" is not the only relevant action. George Floyd for example wasn't shot. And neither was Rodney King.

Comment: I agree @Fizz. It was hard to accurately define the question, that's why I asked for "other helpful statistics".

Comment: I’m close this question, then, because it is already answered on skeptics stack exchange. If you are looking for any more information on the topic which can not be found in the linked question, please edit your question to specify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: there's a lot fewer black people to shoot, which would make it hard to have "more", but they sure give it shot...